# FTP BAT file - Windows Scheduled Task

Tags: backup, ftp, batch, scheduled-tasks

Is it possible to create a scheduled task in windows, that connects to an FTP site, and downloads all the files and folders within the root directory (or specified folders in the root directory) - for example \httdocs and \subdomains to a local directory?

I figure it must be possible, however i can't quite think of the syntax....

This is to backup my website, to the local drive - i edit and upload content to it (it's wordpress) from various sources.

Comment: @alex: as per your comment for @djhowell: click RUN > cmd ... type in ftp ... see what happens ... if you get ftp> prompt - your script should work just fine ... if not - you don't have c:\windows\server32 n your path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/69929/ftp-script-wont-transfer-remote-files-to-local-computer) for the correct script; thanks @djhowell - your script got me started:

Here's the working script:

```
open ftp.yoursite.com
ftpUsername
ftpPassword
lcd C:\Temp\OrWhatever
cd /DirectoryOnFtpServer
prompt
mget *.*
quit
```

`lcd` - change LOCAL directory
`cd` - change REMOTE directory
`mget *.*` - get all files in directory

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible using scripting mode (ftp -s). Put something like this in a .BAT file:

```
ftp -s:MyFTP.txt
```

And then create a MyFTP.txt file in the same path that contains something like this:

```
open ftp.example.com
myusername
mypassword
lcd C:\Backup
mget *
quit
```

Or specify multiple directories like

```
mget httdocs\*
mget subdomains\*
```

Comment: i tried this, when i execute the bat file, it just prints ftp -s:MyFTP.txt over and over..... it doesn't seem to try and connect....

Comment: Don't call your batch file "ftp.bat", because windows doesn't know whether to call ftp.bat or ftp.exe. Name your batch file something like "ftpfiles.bat". thread necro FTW!