# FTP script won't transfer remote files to local computer

Tags: script, ftp, batch-file

This is a follow up to [FTP BAT file - Windows Scheduled Task](https://superuser.com/questions/52440/ftp-bat-file-windows-scheduled-task).

I copied the FTP script, but I can't transfer the files to my local computer.

All I get is this (server address omitted):

```
331 Password required for ftpdemo.

230 User ftpdemo logged in.
ftp> lcd C:\Temp\Test
Local directory now C:\Temp\Test.
ftp> mget ErrorLog\*.*
200 Type set to A.
mget LogViewer.asp? quit
ftp>
```

Here's the actual script:

```
open ftp.myserver.com
ftpdemo
pass
lcd C:\Temp\Test
mget ErrorLog\*.*
quit
```

What do I need to fix?

#### UPDATE:

used PROMPT, now it loops through all the files, but keeps saying the following:

```
200 port command successful
550 "file_name_here": no such file
```

and same goes for every file in the directory ... it lists all the files, so they ARE there, I have no idea what's wrong. Also, I use the same account that I use for GUI ftp, and permissions should not be an issue.

Any ideas?

#### UPDATE 2:

here's how i got it to work (thanks to [dave lozinski's site](http://www.davelozinski.com/tutorials/ftp/index.php?1258103274503)):

```
open ftp.myserver.com
ftpdemo
pass
lcd C:\Temp\Test
cd /ErrorLog
prompt
mget *.*
quit
```

basically I just had to change the directory on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the mget command add a line that says

```
prompt
```

Comment: now this goes thru all files on remote folder, but keeps saying "port command successful. no such file" ... all files are there though ... any ideas?

Comment: didn't solve the issue but helped me get starter, thanx

Comment: did you fix why the files weren't coming down?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `ftp -i` will solve the problem.

This parameter turns off interactive prompting during multiple file transfers, which is the prompt that I see in the post.

Comment: same results ... loops thru all the files in the folder, and keeps saying "no such file" but all the files are there ... i use the same credentials as i use for GUI ftp access, so permissions should not be the issue ... any ideas?