# Scheduling program execution and file moves

Tags: windows, ftp, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for some high-level suggestions on how to build the following:

During the process of about two weeks, a few jobs will need to run a few times a day, at very precisely given times. These jobs include:

- Pulling/pushing files from/to FTP servers.
- Running an SSIS (that's Microsoft's ETL solution) package.
- Running a C# program that's compiled as `.exe`.

All of this happens on Windows Servers.

As a programmer, my first thought was to write a tool in C# that can run for a couple of weeks, and just executes these other tasks at the given points in time. This sounds like overkill and difficult to maintain, though.

What would your solution be?

Comment: So why don't use just use Windows Scheduler?

Comment: [FTP BAT file – Windows Scheduled Task](https://superuser.com/q/52440/150988) may be relevant.

Comment: You can automate from Task Scheduler as Martin suggestion and then time out a batch script to run the FTP uploads and downloads, and then schedule the SSIS package with SQL Agent job accordingly. This all seems like basic and simple tasks even with everything you mention. So WinSCP for the FTP automation, a batch script to kick off FTP scripts using WinSCP, SQL Agent Jobs for the SQL part then SSIS or another batch for the exe depending on the order it needs to run, etc.